# Angular datatable search filter on "search" press

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using server side processing with angular datatable. Is there anyway to turn off auto filtering in the search box and make it to search/filter (ajax call to server side) only when search button is click. Hope someone experience in angular datatable can help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular at all, but in normal datatables it's simply a case of unbinding the keyup event on the search input, and adding a button with a click event that calls 'draw()' or 'fnDraw()' or w/e the angular equivalent is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in 4 steps :

- unbind all event handlers associated with the default search box
- add a new search button next to the search box
- include a DataTable directive instance (`dtInstance`)
- perform search via `dtInstance` when the new search button is clicked

Use the `initComplete` callback to make the modifications, example :

```js
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  //other options 
  .withOption('initComplete', function() {
     $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind();
     $('<button/>').text('search').attr('id', 'new-search').appendTo('.dataTables_filter');
     $('#new-search').on('click', function() { 
       $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.search($('.dataTables_filter input').val()).draw();
     })  
   })
```

Include the directive instance

```js
$scope.dtInstance = {};
```

```html
<table datatable dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" >
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/afMNeuUbwolGPffTdson?p=preview**

Comment: appreciate for the reply. How could this be extend to accommodation multiple search filter input?

Comment: @vincentsty, what do you mean by "_multiple search filter input_"? I thought this question was about disabling the default auto search and trigger it by a button click instead.

Comment: How I can add class to search button?

Comment: How should I can get search value on serve side from query string?

Comment: Hey @MuhammadShahzad, you can add an `addClass` to the chain : `$('<button/>').addClass('yourClass').text('search')....`. Regarding serverside processing it completely depends on your setup http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing You must have a service (or serverside script) that responds properly to the request, and that varys a lot - see the link for details.

Comment: Thank you so much :) This method must be built-in